# How can i call a operator overloaded member function(or use the operator) from another operator overloading member function in the same class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm writing a code in c++ for handling Complex numbers. I was also practicing operator overloading too. So I overloaded `*`(multiplication operator), now I want to use the overloaded operator in my overloaded `/`(division operator), but when I'm using `*` its showing error. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Imaginary
{
    public:
    //constructors
    Imaginary(double a,double b):x(a),y(b){}
    Imaginary():x(0.0),y(0.0){}

    //setter methods for x and y
    void Setx(double x) { this->x = x; }
    void Sety(double y) { this->y = y; }

    //getter methods for x and y
    double Getx(){return this->x;}
    double Gety(){return this->y;}

    //overloaded operators
    Imaginary operator+(Imaginary&);
    Imaginary operator-(Imaginary&);
    Imaginary operator*(Imaginary&);
    Imaginary operator~();
    Imaginary operator/(Imaginary&);

    void print();
private:
    double x;
    double y;
};

Imaginary Imaginary::operator+(Imaginary &i){
    Imaginary ti;
    ti.Setx(this->x+i.x);
    ti.Sety(this->y+i.y);

    return ti;
}

Imaginary Imaginary::operator-(Imaginary &i){
    Imaginary ti;
    ti.Setx(this->x-i.x);
    ti.Sety(this->y-i.y);
    return ti;
}

Imaginary Imaginary::operator*(Imaginary &i){
Imaginary ti;
ti.Setx((this->x*i.x) - (this->y*i.y));
ti.Sety((this->y*i.x)+(this->x*i.y));
return ti;
}

Imaginary Imaginary::operator~(){
int y;
y = this->y;
this->y = -y;
return *this;
}

Imaginary Imaginary ::operator/(Imaginary &i){
Imaginary numerator,denominator,ti;
//i want to use here the overloaded *(multiplacation) operator
numerator = (*this) * (~i);//showing error
denominator = (*this) * (~i);//showing error
ti.Setx(numerator.Getx()/denominator.Getx());
ti.Sety(numerator.Gety()/denominator.Getx());

return ti;
}

void Imaginary::print(){
cout<<x;
if (y>0)
cout<<"+i"<<y<<endl;
else if (y<0)
cout<<"-i"<<abs(y)<<endl;

}

int main()
{   
Imaginary res;
Imaginary z1(2,3);
Imaginary z2(1,-1);
z1.print();
z2.print();

/*res = z1+z2;
cout<<"Addition:-\n";
res.print();

res = z1-z2;
cout<<"Subtraction:-\n";
res.print()*/

res = z1*z2;
cout<<"Multiplication:-\n";
res.print();

res = z1/z2;
cout<<"Division:-\n";
res.print();

return 0;
}
```

the error message is following:-

```
D:\Games\Cheese\main.cpp|66|error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'Imaginary' and 'Imaginary')|
```

Please anybody show me how to rectify it.

Comment: A (possible) problem with with your implementation is that the division changes the operand `i` which is probably unintended. Since it is 2x complement it is changed back. This is why you should mark the parameters and function as `const` where you don't intend to change the parameter or object itself (here every operator except `operator~` , that changes object itself), so `...::operatorx(const Imaginary &i) const`.

Answer (score 2):

The error isn't the best one in this case.  Your `operator*` is defined as

```
Imaginary Imaginary::operator*(Imaginary &i)
```

Which requires the right hand side to be an lvalue.  When you do

```
(*this) * (~i)
```

in `operator/`, `(~i)`returns `Imaginary` which is a rvalue.  You cannot bind that rvalue to the lavue reference so your overload is not considered and you get a compiler error.

The simplest way to fix this is to take a `const &` instead like

```
Imaginary Imaginary::operator*(const Imaginary &i)
```

Comment: The operator can be `const` as well.

Comment: Pardon me,What is lvaule and rvalue??

Comment: @UzumakiSaptarshi See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues

Answer (score 0):

Two things

Firstly,

```
 (*this)*(~i);
```

is an expression in which the right hand side (result of `operator~()`) is a temporary.   Your `operator*()` can only accept a temporary as a reference argument (`Imaginary &`)if that argument is declared `const`.

Also both sides of an `operator*()` are better specified as `const`, since - generally speaking - multiplying two values does not change either one (and produces a distinct result).   Same goes for other operators (like `operator/()`).

The solution is to change the specification of `operator*()` (member function) to be

```
Imaginary Imaginary::operator*(const Imaginary &i) const;
```

Having done that, an alternative way of calling the `operator*()` would be to replace

```
numerator = (*this) * (~i);
```

with

```
numerator = this->operator*(~i);
```

or even (since this is happening in a member function) with

```
numerator = operator*(~i);     //  this-> is implied
```